# Apply selector on sub elements with cheerio

Tags: typescript, cheerio

I've found no way for applying selectors on [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/) elements (version 1.0.0-rc.3). Using [`find()`](https://cheerio.js.org/#traversing) raises an error.

```
const xmlText = `
<table>
  <tr><td>Foo</td><td/></tr>
  <tr><td>1,2,3</td><td>number</td></tr>
  <tr><td>A,B</td><td>char</td></tr>
  <!-- more rows -->
</table>
<table>
  <tr><td>Bar</td><td/></tr>
  <!-- more rows -->
</table>
`
const $ = cheerio.load(xmlText)
$('table').each((i, table) => {
  // TODO if first row contains Foo then map the following rows
  if (table.find("td:contains('Foo')").length > 0) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

> Property 'find' does not exist on type 'CheerioElement'.

How can I apply selectors of sub elements?

The given example should only process table with first row text `Foo` and return the following list of objects.

```
// desired result
[{ value: '1,2,3', type: 'numbner' }, { value: 'A,B', type: 'char' }, ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the documentation of [`each()`](https://cheerio.js.org/#each-functionindex-element-) method. You have to wrap the given `element` like `$(element)`.

```
if ($(table).find("td:contains('Foo')").length > 0) {
```

Finally I solved the problem.

```
const $ = cheerio.load(xmlText)
const isFooTable = (i: number, e: CheerioElement) =>
  $('td', e).first().text() === 'Foo'
const result: { value: string; type: string }[] = []

$('table')
  .filter(isFooTable)
  .find('tr')
  .slice(1)
  .each((_, tr) => {
    const tds = $(tr).find('td')
    result.push({
      value: tds.first().text(),
      type: tds.last().text(),
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Written from scratch, I'm sure there's a better way to do this:

```
$('table').each((i, table) => { if ($(table).find("td:contains('Foo')").length > 0) {$('tr', table).each((i, tr)=>{console.log($(tr).text())})} })
```